# Retrieving data from Mongodb and show it on front-end using django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, web-deployment

I have a mongodb database named as `world`, which has two collection from before `city`, `languages`. I want to show the data of my collection on  the web, how can i do it.

currently i know to create `collection` in `models.py` and migrate it. like;
first we have to edit databases[] in `setting.py`

```
DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'djongo',
           'NAME': 'world',
       }
   }
```

in `models.py` i creted a class and migrated it using `python manage.py migrate`

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc=models.TextField()
```

and i'm able to retrieve data from `Destination` by using below code in `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination
def index(request):
    dests=Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests})
```

My question is my collection/class is already available in the database ( `city`, `language`) and i'm not creating it contrary to `Destination` which was defined by me. then how to show data of `city` collection of `world` database on the front-end.
kindly looking for help.

Comment: Why don't you use something like this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fetch-data-from-mongodb-using-python/

Comment: @AMK well i have tried doing that, but here we are fetching data directly from mongoDB sever, so data is shown on front-end only once, and if you refresh your webpage, everything will disappear. and you will need to restart the server to view database. the error that server info is Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 59579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you properly, then you have a MongoDB database called `world`.
There you stored `city` and `languages` before you started to set up Django.
Then you added a `Destination` model, thus created a new collection.
For now, you're looking for a way how to get `city` and `languages` collections data similar way as you do with `Destination`.

So there are multiple ways how you could handle it:

1. Create Django models for `city` and `languages` collections (define fields that you have in existing collections):

```
class City(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city'  # important, should be your existing collection name

class Language(models.Model):
    field3 = ...
    field4 = ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'languages'  # important, should be your existing collection name
```

Now you're ready to use `City` and `Language` the same way as you do with the `Destination` model.

2. Use `PyMongo` (this is already installed as you're using `Djongo`). So your snipped will look something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination
import pymongo

# default localhost connection URL
MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
mongo_db = connection.world


def index(request):
    collection_city = db['city']
    collection_languages = db['languages']

    cities = list(collection_city.find())
    languages = list(collection_languages.find())
    dests=Destination.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html', 
        {
            'dests': dests, 
            'cities': cities,
            'languages': languages
        }
    )
```

I'd use **option 1**, as it allows you to keep the project coherent.

Comment: also if you could suggest me some related resource to learn these super helpful things. i will be grateful. and i would be glad connecting you on Linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/gourav-kumar-singh-b25164191/

Comment: I think method 1 is best suitable when we have Uniform data, and method 2 in the case when we have a data when our schemas varies with documents in collection.

Comment: @def__init__ you're welcome. I'm not sure what I'd suggest you read, except the official `Django` and `PyMongo` docs. Just try to think about what you have, then try to imagine any possible solutions with the tool pack you have.

Comment: may you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862269/hide-and-show-elements-inside-django-html-template